# gform_after_submission does not work on ajax enabled form

Tags: ajax, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a Gravity Forms multi-step form. I need to run my own function when the form is submitted so I'm using the GF hook 'gform_after_submission'

The hook works perfectly on forms that do not utilize AJAX. Since the multi-step form uses AJAX; upon clicking on 'Submit', the form doesn't do anything and the spinner keeps loading.

I know if I could disable AJAX on submit then it would work but there's nothing in GF documentation that shows how I can disable AJAX on form submit (because I still need AJAX for going back and forth the form).

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'client_registration_process', 10, 2 );
function client_registration_process( $entry, $form ) {

    if ( !empty($form) ) {

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $form );
        echo "</pre>";
        die;
    }
}
```

Please suggest how I can overcome this issue. Thanks!

Comment: You really should ask that question the Gravity Forms support.

Comment: @kero I'm developing this site for a client who is using the free version of the plugin. The support won't help you unless you have a paid license.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but third party plugins are off topic on WordPress.StackExchange, as you can read in the [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. I have seen a lot of questions on third-party plugins here.

Comment: Yeah, me too. Usually when I know a plugin, I still try to help, but I don't know Gravity Forms, sorry.

Comment: No problem. We are human after all; can't know everything.